# Arm workout similar to P4P's ab series?

Tags: exercise, workout, upper-body-workout, biceps

I've been doing the 8 min ab exercises from [passion4profession](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44mgUselcDU), and would like to do something similar for my arms.

The exercises in the video are all done without any equipment, they work their way up from very easy to very hard, and everything seems very professional. I'm having trouble finding any similar routines for the upper-body. I only have a chin up bar and a couple weights, so anything beyond that I wouldn't be able to do.

Does anyone know of a similar program for arms?

edit: Also, I'm aware of the p90x, but I definitely won't be doing that. I'm not looking to "get into the best shape of my life," I just want to incorporate some fitness into my otherwise sedentary lifestyle.

Answer (score 0):

The chin-up bar, combined with bench press and overhead press with the few weights that you have should be enough for a very beginner upper-body strength program. There are much better programs, but with your limited goals and supplies, something like this should work:

Workout A:

- Bench press
- Chin-ups (3 sets to failure)

Workout B:

- Overhead press
- Pull-ups (3 sets to failure)

Alternate these every second day, leaving one rest day between them. (A, rest, B, rest, A, rest,...)

About bench press and overhead press, I don't know what weights you have, so can't really prescribe a rep/set range for you. If you only have a couple of dumbbells, just do 3 sets to failure. If you have several weights of dumbbells, use a weight that lets you only do 5-15 reps before moving up to the next weight, but pick a smaller range, depending on what you're looking for (4-6 for strength, 12-15 for size).